# How to get asterisk in placeholder with css

Tags: html, css

I want to add an asterisk mark to placeholder of inputs. Something like this:
[image]

I have searched internet but could not find a working solution.

**My current approach:**

Currently I am trying to add it in the after pseudo element but that is not appearing.

```css
    input[type=text]::-webkit-input-placeholder:after {
       content: '*';
       color: red; vertical-align: top; font-size: 10px;
    }
    
    input[type=text]:-moz-placeholder:after { /* Firefox 18- */
       content: '*'; 
       color: red; vertical-align: top; font-size: 10px;
    }
    
    input[type=text]::-moz-placeholder:after {  /* Firefox 19+ */
       content: '*';
       color: red; vertical-align: top; font-size: 10px;
    }
    
    input[type=text]:-ms-input-placeholder:after {  
       content: '*';
       color: red; vertical-align: top; font-size: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="your-name" placeholder="Naam">
```

I do not want to add the symbol directly in the placeholder. But would love it in any other way that will let me style the symbol differently.( say I want blue color for my symbol but rest of the text in grey).

So, if anyone can help me add an asterisk to the placeholder.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/KiranKumarDash/987tybdg/1/)**

Comment: @BhojendraNepal But that will not let me style it. Suppose I want to add a different color to the asterisk symbol.

Comment: The **asterisk** sign is meant to be kept in the label to show the field as mandatory and not on the placeholder.

Comment: Yes @Shashank. But my client wants me to add it in placeholder too. So, I am looking for a way if that can be done.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal. Can you please guide me on how I can do that?

Comment: I've answered for you.

Comment: Show the client the accessibility test; in this case colour contrast will likely fail; you need a required attribute on the label too, not just an asterix, and not just an asterix in the text field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you simply use * in placeholder attribute itself?

```css
.asterisk::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color:    #f00;
}
.asterisk:-moz-placeholder {
   color:    #f00;
   opacity:  1;
}
.asterisk::-moz-placeholder {
   color:    #f00;
   opacity:  1;
}
.asterisk:-ms-input-placeholder {
   color:    #f00;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="your_name" placeholder="*" class="asterisk" />
```

EndNote: You can't use pseudo elements in [replaced html elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element)

---

As per your comment you can also use required attribute and then style them like this:

```
<input type="text" name="your_name" placeholder="*" required />
[required]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color:    #f00;
}
```

As per your next comment requirement, you need to wrap your input which needs asterisks in a span like below:

```css
.input-group{
  position: relative;
}
.input-group::after{
  content: '*';
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 46px;
  color: #f00
}
```

```html
<span class="input-group">
  <input type="text" name="your_name" placeholder="Naam" />
</span>
```

Comment: But that will add the color to entire placeholder. What I want is : Only the asterisk symbol in placeholder to come in grey and other text in placeholder to come in red.

Comment: Oh sorry. You got me wrong. see my question. In my placeholder I am having "Naam" but it should display "Naam * " with asterisk in a red color.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by calculating the text length, and passing it to your css for better responsiveness.

```
  const placeHolderLength = (placeholder.length) ? placeholder.length : 1 ;
  const placeHolderCalculate = placeHolderLength * 10 + 'px';



 .input-group{
  position: relative;
}
.input-group::after{
  content: '*';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: var(--placeholder-text);
  color: #f00
}
```